# problem with my dockerfile and wildfly configuration

Tags: java, spring, docker, wildfly

I have a problem with my dockerfile and wildfly configuration.
I am using the following Dockerfile as a base:
https://github.com/mosaic-hgw/WildFly/blob/master/Dockerfile
Which I have extended according to the needs of my Private project.
I want to migrate my existing project to Docker, but when deploying the WAR file, I get the following error message that I don't understand.

> 0:06:29,480 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'Scheduler' in deployment unit 'deployment "ROOT.war"' are as follows:

```
java:global/ROOT/Scheduler!com.monck.core.scheduling.Scheduler
java:app/ROOT/Scheduler!com.monck.core.scheduling.Scheduler
java:module/Scheduler!com.monck.core.scheduling.Scheduler
java:global/ROOT/Scheduler
java:app/ROOT/Scheduler
java:module/Scheduler
```

10:06:29,481 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'Mail' in deployment unit 'deployment "ROOT.war"' are as follows:

```
java:global/ROOT/Mail!com.monck.core.mail.Mail
java:app/ROOT/Mail!com.monck.core.mail.Mail
java:module/Mail!com.monck.core.mail.Mail
java:global/ROOT/Mail
java:app/ROOT/Mail
java:module/Mail
```

Now the error:

> 10:06:33,316 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ROOT.war")]) - failure description: {
> "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.monck"],
> "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
> "jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".component.Mail.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.monck]",
> "jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".component.Scheduler.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.monck]",
> "jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.monck]"
> ]
> }

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

($JBOSS_CLI -c "/subsystem=security/security-domain=monck:add(cache-type=default)")  && \